# How can I write Jsonresult into text file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I have web api. I want to write json result into text file for logging.
I am using below code.

```
  FileStream sb = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/log.txt"), FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sb);

            sw.Write("\r\n " + DateTime.Now);
            sw.Write("\r\n ResultsetID: " + resultSetID);

            var result =  Json(NotificationsSecurity.GetUsersByResultSet(_context, resultSetID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

How can I write result into text file without deserializing?

Comment: sw.Write(result.ToString())?

Comment: I tried that , its only writing System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult into my log file.

Answer (score -1):

try this , with javascript it might help   !

```
 var json = <%= result %>
 var choiceContainer1 = $("#lbl");
 choiceContainer1.append('<br/><label>'+json+'</lable>');
```

Comment: Is there any other way in mvc? I can't add javascript code.